# Get text file as input in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the text file as input but I am getting only null value...

```
public ActionResult add_content()
    {


        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult add_content(HttpPostedFileBase d)
    {


        return View();
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <form action="http://localhost:49416/g1/add_content" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="d" />
    <input type="submit" name=" add content" />
</form>
```

I have included the screenshot with breakpoint [image: breaking point picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: 
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file"> Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

You were missing the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` 
Also it is important to note that input name must be the same in controller.